# One div taking over another one when zooming

Tags: html, css, css-position

When I'm zooming out the page images at the bottom are taking over my other image (background) at the top. When I'm zooming in there's blank space on the right side. And my footer is missing as well. 
How to fix this?
https://jsfiddle.net/egdeLy1c/

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Properties for background image here */
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://citywallpaperhd.com/download/71-huge-impressive-city-at-night.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


#logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}


#navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li {
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a {
    padding: 5px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a.current {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px; 
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #ff9900;
}


#banner-text {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 250px 50px; 
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#banner-text p {
    width: 800px; 
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}


#main-content img, #main-content-2 img{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="navigation">

            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>

            <ul>
                <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="banner-text">
            <h1>h1 text</h1>
            <p>
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/>
   </div>
   
   <div id="main-content-2">
     <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/>
   </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey :) I can't reproduce the zoom in out issue. But i brought your footer back.

If you are floating elements you need to add a Clearfix to them. Here you can read more about the clear fix and floats

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

And for the header-img don't add %-height if you want it always the same height. Go with a fixed height with pixel... For example 750px.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

/*Clearfix*/

   .clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Properties for background image here */
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    background-image: url("http://citywallpaperhd.com/download/71-huge-impressive-city-at-night.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


#logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}


#navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li {
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a {
    padding: 5px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a.current {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px; 
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #ff9900;
}


#banner-text {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 250px 50px; 
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#banner-text p {
    width: 800px; 
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}


#main-content img, #main-content-2 img{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="navigation">

            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>

            <ul>
                <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="banner-text">
            <h1>h1 text</h1>
            <p>
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content" class="clearfix">
        <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/>
   </div>
   
   <div id="main-content-2" class="clearfix">
     <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/>
   </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: I finished editing now :D now you can check it out. Coding on mobile is horrible